# Matching pattern on multiple lines

Tags: sed

I have a file as below

```
NAME(BOLIVIA)              TYPE(SA)
APPLIC(Java)                 IP(192.70.xxx.xx)
NAME(BOLIVIA)              TYPE(SA)
APPLIC(Java)                 IP(192.71.xxx.xx)
```

I am trying to extract the values NAME and IP using sed:

```
cat file1  |
sed ':a
N
$!ba
s/\n/ /g' |         sed -n 's/.*\(NAME(BOLI...)\).*\(IP(.*)\).*/\1 \2/p'
```

However, I'm only getting the output:

```
NAME(BOLIVIA) IP(192.71.xxx.xx)
```

What I would like is:

```
NAME(BOLIVIA) IP(192.70.xxx.xx)
NAME(BOLIVIA) IP(192.71.xxx.xx)
```

Would appreciate it if someone could give me a pointer on what I'm missing.

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first `sed` commands reformats the file into one long line. You could have used `tr -d "\n"` for this, but that is not the problem.
The problem is in the second part, where the `.*` greedy eats as much as possible until finding the last match.

Your solution could be "fixed" with the ugly

```
# Do not use this:
sed -zn 's/[^\n]*\(NAME(BOLI...)\)[^\n]*\n[^\n]*\(IP([^)]*)\)[^\n]*/\1 \2/gp' file1
```

Possible solutions:

```
cat file1 | paste -d " " - - | sed -n 's/.*\(NAME(BOLI...)\).*\(IP(.*)\).*/\1 \2/p'
# or
grep -Eo "(NAME\(BOLI...\)|IP\(.*\))" file1 | paste -d " " - -
# or
printf "%s %s\n" $(grep -Eo "(NAME\(BOLI...\)|IP\(.*\))" file1)
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for showing multiple ways of skinning this cat!

Answer (score 4):

In case you are ok with `awk` could you please try following. Written and tested in link
https://ideone.com/bJDzgf with shown samples only.

```
awk '
match($0,/^NAME\([^)]*/){
  name=substr($0,RSTART+5,RLENGTH-5)
  next
}
match($0,/IP\([^)]*/){
  print name,substr($0,RSTART+3,RLENGTH-3)
  name=""
}
' Input_file
```

Comment: `awk` is a goood choice for processing conditions on several lines. Your solution is better than `awk '/NAME\(BOLIV/ {get_ip=1; printf $1; next}; get_ip==1 {print " " $NF}'` that would fail with other input (different first/last field).

Comment: Hmm, good that I didn't post my `awk` as an answer. `{print " " $NF}` should have been `{print " " $NF; get_ip=0;}`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution RavinderSingh13. Thanks also for the reference to ideone. Never came across that site before till you mentioned it!

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/NAME/{N;/IP/s/\s.*\s/ /p}' file
```

If a line contains `NAME` and the following line contains `IP` remove everything between and print the result.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative shorter `awk`:

```sh
awk '$1 ~ /^NAME/ {nm = $1} $2 ~ /^IP/ {print nm, $2}' file

NAME(BOLIVIA) IP(192.70.xxx.xx)
NAME(BOLIVIA) IP(192.71.xxx.xx)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your script is the use `.*` which matches in a `greedy` way
so that you have only the first `NAME(BOLI...)` and last `IP(.*)`

If you can use python :

```
#!/bin/bash

python -c '
import re, sys
for ar in re.findall(r"(NAME\(BOLI.*?\)).*?(IP\(.*?\))", sys.stdin.read(), re.DOTALL):
    print(*ar)
' < input-file
```